# How to set the WPF StrokeDashArray from Code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can i know how to set the StrokeDashArray from code behind? I try to use the method like the way how to set the margin...but it doesn't work.

The following is my code:

```
public static void DrawCircle(MainWindow main)
    {
        Ellipse myCircle = new Ellipse();
        myCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Orange;
        myCircle.Width = 25;
        myCircle.Height = 25;
        myCircle.StrokeThickness = 2;
        myCircle.StrokeDashArray = new System.Windows.Thickness("2,2,2,2");

        Canvas.SetLeft(myCircle, 10);
        Canvas.SetRight(myCircle, 10);
        Canvas.SetBottom(myCircle, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(myCircle, 20);
        main.MyCanvas.Children.Add(myCircle);

    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Problem is this line

```
myCircle.StrokeDashArray = new System.Windows.Thickness("2,2,2,2");
```

StrokeDashArray is a [DoubleCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.doublecollection.aspx)

Try this instead

```
myCircle.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 2 };
```